# Rate limit AWS API gateway endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

AWS API Gateway provides a way to rate limit requests using the **Usage plan** for different users.

But the rate limit is applicable for all end-points.
So, if I have a `GET` request and another `POST` request endpoints, can I set different limits for the `GET` request and separate limit for the `POST` requests?

Example:

**GET request end-point**

```
https://aws.api.gateway/v1/get_data <- set rate limit to 10,000
```

**POST request end-point**

```
https://aws.api.gateway/v1/post_data <- set rate limit to 100
```

The POST requests is a costly operation, hence I would want to limit the number of requests by a certain user whereas allow for a large number of `GET` requests.

*Requirement is basically to have 2 different rate limits for 2 different end-points.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have two different rate limits for two different endpoints.

If you go to your gateway's stages and click one of the endpoints, you'll see something like this...

[image: Default settings]

So, by default all endpoints use your stage-level rate limits. But you choose "Override for this method", you'll get this...

[image: Override settings]

You can then set your method-level rate limit for that HTTP method.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html#how-to-stage-settings

> 8. To override the stage-level throttling for individual methods, expand the stage under the Stages secondary navigation pane, choose a method of interest, and, back in the stage editor, choose Override for this method for Settings. In the Default Method Throttling area, select appropriate options.